# Every point of the interval $(0,1)$ is an interior point of that interval. Thus $(0,1)^0 = (0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving

This is a question I found here (on pg.2 example 1.2.2): http://web.pdx.edu/~erdman/PTAC/problemtext_pdf.pdf

Definition of interior and interior point: Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  The point $a$ is an interior point on $A$ if some $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $a$ lies entirely in $A$.  The set of all interior points of $A$ is denoted $A^0$ and is called the interior.

The book gives this proof:  Let $a$ be an arbitrary point in $(0,1)$.  Choose $\epsilon$ to be the smaller of the numbers $a$ and $1-a$.  Then $J_{\epsilon}(a)=(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon) \subseteq (0,1)$ (because $\epsilon \le a$ implies $a-\epsilon \ge 0$, and $\epsilon \le 1-a$ implies $a+\epsilon \le 1$).

My question.  In the reasoning noted in parenthesis at the end, shouldn't those inequalities be strict inequalities rather than having the "or equals" part?  My example is if $a=0.5$.  You would not want $\epsilon=0.5$ since that would results in that in touching the bounds 0 and 1, which is not part of our interval.  Does this make sense?

Comment: The choice $a=\varepsilon$ clearly fails. Replace all the $\leq,\geq$ by $<,>$.

Comment: But $(0,1) = B_{1/2}(1/2) \subset X = (0,1)$, there is no problem, since the endpoints don't belong to $J_\varepsilon$.

Comment: Oh!  I see what you are saying.  Since by definition, I have assumed an open interval, the inequalities are ok as is.  If I had assumed a closed interval, then the inequalities would need to be stricter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=0.5$ then $\varepsilon=\min(a,\,1-a)=0.5$ and then the neighborhood of $a$ is $(a-\varepsilon,\,a+\varepsilon)\ =\ (0,1)$, does not contain its endpoints.

Of course, you can also choose any $\varepsilon$ that is *smaller or equal* than $\min(a,\,1-a)$.

Comment: Right right.  It's because I defined my neighborhood as an open interval that those inequalities work.  Thanks!